# Get the value of radio group using htmx

Tags: python, htmx

I am using htmx and want my code to be able to retrieve the value of a set item in a radio group.  Here is the htmx that I am trying to use:

```
<div id="js-scale">
            <div>
                <input type=radio name="Js" id="JsStrong"></input>
                <label for="JsStrong">Agree</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type=radio name="Js" id="JsNeutral"></input>
                <label for="JsNetutral">Neutral</label>    
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type=radio name="Js" id="JsPos"></input>
                <label for="JsPos">Disagree</label>    
            </div>
        <div id="control-block">
            <button hx-post={{'/session/'+session+'/tweet/'+tweet+'/Skip'}} hx-trigger="click" hx-swap="innerHTML" hx-target="#session" type="button">Skip</button>
            <button hx-post={{'/session/'+session+'/tweet/'+tweet+'/js_submit'}} hx-trigger="click" hx-swap="innerHTML" hx-target="#session" type="button" hx-include="[name='Js']">Submit</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

When I press `submit`, and in the python use `requests.get_data()`, it returns `Js=on`, irrespective of which radio button has been selected.

How do I set this up to be able to determine which of the radio buttons has been selected?

Answer (score 2):

I found that by explicitly setting the `value` for the button, it works fine.  The correct snippet is:

```
<div id="js-scale">
            <div>
                <input type=radio name="Js" id="JsStrong value="JsStrong"></input>
                <label for="JsStrong">Agree</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type=radio name="Js" id="JsNeutral" value="JsNeutral"></input>
                <label for="JsNetutral">Neutral</label>    
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type=radio name="Js" id="JsPos" value="JsPos"></input>
                <label for="JsPos">Disagree</label>    
            </div>
        <div id="control-block">
            <button hx-post={{'/session/'+session+'/tweet/'+tweet+'/Skip'}} hx-trigger="click" hx-swap="innerHTML" hx-target="#session" type="button">Skip</button>
            <button hx-post={{'/session/'+session+'/tweet/'+tweet+'/js_submit'}} hx-trigger="click" hx-swap="innerHTML" hx-target="#session" type="button" hx-include="[name='Js']">Submit</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

This is because of how HTML works, from the [MDN 'input type=radio' page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio):

> If you omit the value attribute in the HTML, the submitted form data assigns the value on to the group. In this scenario, if the user clicked on the "Phone" option and submitted the form, the resulting form data would be contact=on, which isn't helpful. So don't forget to set your value attributes!